# ionic signed app stuck at white screen on sdk 28 and 29

Tags: android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

the app work well on SDK 27,26.. the problem happens when I try to change the targetSdkVersion to 28 or 29 in config.xml and try to sign the app.
also, the app works well on the simulator and when I export the unsigned app. 
but when I sign the app using android studio or jarsigner, the app stuck on loading page.
I tried to remove android platform and add it again but this didn't solve the problem.

ionic version : 5.4.16
cordova version : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

cordova plugin list:

`cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth 1.5.0 "FingerprintAuth"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.2 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.3 "BackgroundMode"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-crop 0.3.1 "CropPlugin"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.5.8 "cordova-plugin-filepath"
cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio 2.0.0 "FingerprintAllInOne"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-photo-library 2.2.1 "Photo Library"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.1 "Diagnostic"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"`

**and here my package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/android-fingerprint-auth": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-library": "^5.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^5.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.144",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth": "^1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.3",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.6",
    "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-photo-library": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "ngx-post-message": "^1.5.3",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.0.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
},
"description": "An Ionic project",
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-photo-library": {
            "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
        },
        "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": {},
        "cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth": {},
        "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
        "cordova-plugin-camera": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
        "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file": {},
        "phonegap-plugin-multidex": {},
        "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
            "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
            "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {}
    },
```